# Problemas de conexión con sql server y node js

Tags: sql-server, nodejs, api, express, sql-server-2012

espero se encuentren bien.

Estoy teniendo inconvenientes al implementar una api con express js en un servidor con SO windows server 2012 r2 y el motor de base de datos sql server 2012, el problema está en que cuando se ejecuta el codigo del controlador entra en el catch y no se ejecuta el try. Pero cuando realicé las pruebas en mi maquina local todo se ejecutaba perfectamente, cabe destacar que en mi maquina local tengo instalado sql server versión 19.0.1
**En la configuración de la db quité los credenciales por motivos de seguridad**

Sería de gran ayuda que me ayudarán a dar con la solución de este error.

```
const { getConnection, sql } = require('../../config/dbConfig');


const getAllCallsOpen = async (request, response) => {

  // ----> QUERY PARA LISTAR LAS LLAMADAS (SOLAMENTE = MANTENIMIENTO CORRECTIVO)
  const query = `SELECT Case When tblEquipo.FecGarantia > tblServicio.FecIngreso Then 'G' Else 'E' End As TipContrato, 
  tblCliente.CodCliente, tblEquipo.CodEquipo, DateDiff(d, tblServicio.FecIngreso, ISNULL(FecCierre, GetDate())) As Duracion, 
  FecAccion, tblCliente.Nombre AS NomCliente, tblEmpleado.Nombre + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.tblEmpleado.Apellido, '') AS NomEmpleado, 
  tblServicio.FecIngreso, tblServicio.IdEtapa, tblServicio.Prioridad, tblServicio.IdTipServicio, tblServicio.CodServicio, 
  tblServicio.Problema, tblModelo.Nombre + ' ' + tblEquipo.NumSistema AS NomTipEquipo, tblServicio.CodGrupo, 
  tblServicio.CodEmpResponsable, tblServicio.IdEstatus, tblServicio.IdNivel, tblModelo.CodModelo, tblTipEquipo.CodTipEquipo, 
  tblModalidad.CodModalidad, tblLinea.CodLinea, tblLinea.CodDivision, tblCliente.Alias, tblServicio.FecCierre, 
  tblServicio.FecModificacion, tblServicio.FecEtapa, tblServicio.Accion, tblServicio.CodModelo As CodModeloF, CodClienteF 
  FROM tblCliente INNER JOIN tblServicio ON isnull(tblServicio.CodClienteF, tblServicio.CodCliente) = tblCliente.CodCliente 
  INNER JOIN tblEmpleado ON tblEmpleado.CodEmpleado = tblServicio.CodEmpResponsable LEFT JOIN tblEquipo ON 
  tblEquipo.CodEquipo = tblServicio.CodEquipo LEFT JOIN tblModelo ON tblModelo.CodModelo = isnull(tblServicio.CodModelo, 
  tblEquipo.CodModelo) LEFT JOIN tblTipEquipo ON tblTipEquipo.CodTipEquipo = tblModelo.CodTipEquipo LEFT JOIN tblModalidad ON 
  tblModalidad.CodModalidad = tblTipEquipo.CodModalidad LEFT JOIN tblLinea ON tblLinea.CodLinea = tblModalidad.CodLinea 
  LEFT JOIN tblEstado ON tblEstado.CodEstado = tblEquipo.CodEstado Where Not tblServicio.CodServicio is null And 
  IdEstatus = 1 And tblServicio.IdTipServicio = 1 ORDER BY tblServicio.CodServicio DESC`;


  try {
    const pool = await getConnection();


    const result = await pool.request().query(query);

    if (!result.recordsets[0]) {
      return response.status(404).json({ msg: 'NOT_FOUND' });
    } else {
      response.status(200).json(result.recordsets[0])
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Ocurrió un error al solicitar los datos a la base de datos ${error}`);

  }

};
```

```
No se pudo conectar a la base de datos s ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - socket hang up
    at C:\Users\j.hernandez\Desktop\gis-backend\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:70:17
    at Connection.onConnect (C:\Users\j.hernandez\Desktop\gis-backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1012:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Connection.emit (C:\Users\j.hernandez\Desktop\gis-backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1040:18)
    at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\j.hernandez\Desktop\gis-backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1395:12)
    at Connection.socketEnd (C:\Users\j.hernandez\Desktop\gis-backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1415:12)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\j.hernandez\Desktop\gis-backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1155:16)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12) {
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - socket hang up
      at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\j.hernandez\Desktop\gis-backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1395:28)
      at Connection.socketEnd (C:\Users\j.hernandez\Desktop\gis-backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1415:12)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\j.hernandez\Desktop\gis-backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1155:16)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    code: 'ESOCKET',
    isTransient: undefined
  }
}
Ocurrió un error al solicitar los datos a la base de datos TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'request')
```

la configuración de la base de datos es la siguiente

```
const sql = require('mssql');

const getConnection = async () => {

  try {
    const pool = await sql.connect({
      user: 'usuario',
      password: 'contraseña',
      server: 'localhost',
      database: 'nombre de la base de datos',
      options: {
        encrypt: true,
        trustServerCertificate: true
      }
    });


    return pool;

  } catch (error) {
    console.log('No se pudo conectar a la base de datos s',error)
  }
};

module.exports = {
  getConnection,
  sql
};
```

Comment: Esas opciones de encrypt y trustServerCertificate, no aplican para mssql 2012. Por cierto, es una versión bastante vieja de mssql, que creo ya no tiene soporte. ¿Seguro que debes usar esa versión? Y lo otro: si usas un cliente como SSMS o DBeaver, te puedes conectar a la BD mssql 2012?

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo, esa base de datos está en producción, y sí, estoy utilizando SSMS y puedo conectarme a la base de datos y realizar consultas y todo lo demás. Le comenté a mi jefa que tarde o temprano hay que hacer una actualización a la versión más reciente de sql server, con tu experiencia, que crees que pase si se actualiza a sql 19.0.1?

Comment: Je, ha habido cambios en tipos de dato, algunas cosas de TSQL y otras cosillas, pero en términos generales no debería ser taaan traumático. Depende de las características que usen del motor.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41122298/236345), podrías revisar si alguno de estos parámetros adicionales ayuda

```
var config = {
    "user": 'admin',
    "password": 'password',
    "server": 'localhost?',
    "database": 'database_name',
    "port": 1433, //Es una instancia nombrada (named instance)?
    "dialect": "mssql", // este es interesante
    "dialectOptions": {
        "instanceName": "instancianombrada?"
    }
};
```

Es importante que nos aclares si es una instancia nombrada o no. Lo otro sería que probaras explícito con el

```
options: {
   "encrypt": false
}
```

Ya que eso no existe en MSSQL2012 y el cliente tampoco debería intentarlo.